# Notepad++ doesn't apply my custom word style

Tags: notepad++, xml, default-settings

I want to add keywords for system methods/commands like `console`, `document`, `Math`
, ...

Notepad recognizes the keywords, but doesn't format it with the colors...

**stylers.xml**

```
<LexerType name="javascript" desc="Javascript" ext="">
    <WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" styleID="41" fgColor="000000" bgColor="F2F4FF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
    <WordsStyle name="NUMBER" styleID="45" fgColor="FF0000" bgColor="F2F4FF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
    <WordsStyle name="WORD" styleID="46" fgColor="000000" bgColor="F2F4FF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
    <WordsStyle name="KEYWORD" styleID="47" fgColor="000080" bgColor="F2F4FF" fontName="" fontStyle="3" fontSize="" keywordClass="instre1" />

    <!--important line-->
    <WordsStyle name="METHODS" styleID="53" fgColor="008000" bgColor="F2F4FF" fontName="" fontStyle="1" fontSize="" keywordClass="type1">Math</WordsStyle>

    <WordsStyle name="DOUBLESTRING" styleID="48" fgColor="808080" bgColor="F2F4FF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
    <WordsStyle name="SINGLESTRING" styleID="49" fgColor="808080" bgColor="F2F4FF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
    <WordsStyle name="SYMBOLS" styleID="50" fgColor="000000" bgColor="F2F4FF" fontName="" fontStyle="1" fontSize="" />
    <WordsStyle name="REGEX" styleID="52" fgColor="8000FF" bgColor="F2F4FF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
    <WordsStyle name="COMMENT" styleID="42" fgColor="008000" bgColor="F2F4FF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
    <WordsStyle name="COMMENTLINE" styleID="43" fgColor="008000" bgColor="F2F4FF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
    <WordsStyle name="COMMENTDOC" styleID="44" fgColor="008080" bgColor="F2F4FF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" fontSize="" />
</LexerType>
```

**langs.xml**

```
<Language name="javascript" ext="js" commentLine="//" commentStart="/*" commentEnd="*/">
    <Keywords name="instre1">abstract boolean break byte case catch char class const continue debugger default delete do double else enum export extends final finally float for function goto if implements import in instanceof int interface long native new package private protected public return short static super switch synchronized this throw throws transient try typeof var void volatile while with true false prototype</Keywords>
    <Keywords name="type1">console document</Keywords>
</Language>
```

I noticed that in a .js file (above js in html) the background got minimalistly highlighted.

Comment: well I noticed that notepad++ changed the formatting of the config files so this question is outdated